# mvc - multiple domains for single page with single login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have MVC 4 website, where are 4 access points :

```
1.www.domain.com
2.    domain.com

3.www.domain.net
4.    domain.net
```

Problem is, that when user is logged on one of these url addresses, then user is not logged on another urls. So, for example after login to "www.domain.com" user is not logged in to "domain.com", this behavior applies for all access points.

User can be logged on all access points in same time, but he must fill login form 4 times.

There can be URL rewrite from non-www to www, but there are still 2 domains (.com/.net).

In IIS are all hostname shapes in single site bindings.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please fix your punctuation in the one sentence where you explain your problem? The way you've written it makes it almost impossible to understand the situation you're dealing with.

Comment: sure, sorry, hope that's better

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163432/cross-domain-token-based-authentication-using-asp-net-identity-and-asp-net-web-a

Comment: What Umair said about domain forwarding is definitely the easiest way to avoid this problem.

Comment: thank you for your replies, I'll do it as said Umair, finally it looks as simplest and most effective solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a website with similar domain extensions, including the https protocol, I forwarded all other domains to https://www.domain.com, its good for SEO reasons as well and for your analytics, I would suggest forward all domains to one single domain.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26260626/1158845) also says:

> So, how to share the authentication cookie across multiple domains?
>   Well, there is absolutely no way to do that. The fundamental barrier
>   of the HTTP protocol prevents you from sharing a cookie across
>   different domains, primarily for security reasons.
>
> ...There is no built-in mechanism in ASP.NET to implement a Single
>   Sign On across these two different sites.

You can redirect the website using web.config file by setting up sites in IIS to the redirect folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.domainname.com$S$Q" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thank you very much, I'll do it this way, so you have rules in IIS - URL rewrite, or your implementation of this forwarding is somewhere like in beginrequest or on similar place?

Comment: You can set this up on IIS or on your hosting provider in your DNS records (better option)

Comment: I use a web.config for this, check this [config settings](https://gist.github.com/mumair85/8616eaf810256e849906) (answer updated)

Answer (score 0):

If all of them display same content, just use one domain as the main. Else you can use oauth as single login.